# How to increment the two text box values when button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // This button will increment the value
  $('.qtyplus').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    //alert(fieldName);
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
      $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal + 1000);
    } else {
      $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(1000);
    }
  });
});

function buttonClick() {
  //alert("hi");
  var n = document.getElementById('rs').value;
  alert(n);
  var i = 50;
  if (i == 50) {
    alert(i);
    var n = +n + +i;
    alert(n);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3> Calculator</h3>
<table style="width: 30%;">
  <form name="calc" action="" method="post">
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>quantity:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="value1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>price:</td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' name='quantity' value='2000' class='qty' />
        <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' onclick="buttonClick()" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>discount:</td>
      <td><input type='text' name='rs' value='500' field='rs' id='rs' class='counter' onclick="buttonClick()" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>
```

In above HTML code, when button is clicked, I have to increment the two text box values

For example, click a button, price text box value will be 3000, discount text box value will be 550
price text box value is incremented, but discount value will not be changed.
Second script are run,but the text box value are not changed.

Comment: which are the 2 text field you wanted to update one i understood its `price` input field and about `discount` as far as i understand you don't want to update that so which one is the 2 text field to update and also please let me know the logic behind  `var i = 50; if (i == 50) {}`. because you are assigning value to `i` just before that `checking` so this will always come as `50` hence it will always return true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forget to change the value of the discount input.

```
<script type="text/javascript">//second script
    function buttonClick() {
        //alert("hi");
        var n = document.getElementById('rs').value;
        alert(n);
        var i = 50;
        if (i == 50) {
            alert(i);
            var n = +n + +i;
            alert(n);
            $("#rs").val(n) // add this line
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not written anything to change value of discount textbox.

you can do as follows:

```
$('.qtyplus').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
            qty = $('.qty').val();
            discount = $('#rs').val();

            var currentQtyVal = parseInt(qty);
            if (!isNaN(currentQtyVal)) {
                $('input[name=quantity]').val(currentQtyVal + 1000);
            } else {
                $('input[name=quantity]').val(1000);
            }

            var currentDiscountVal = parseInt(discount);
             if (!isNaN(currentDiscountVal)) {
                $('input[name=rs]').val(currentDiscountVal + 50);
            } else {
                $('input[name=rs]').val(50);
            }
        });
```